# Use plugin directly inside flutter project without separating to another package or adding plugin field in pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, plugins, channel

I want to create a plugin to use in my project. I wonder that how I can call or setup it for invoking from flutter application without specific it in pubspec.yaml (because I use some other packages which also use their owned plugins, if I specify my plugin inside pubspec.yaml, those plugins do not work) or separating to another package.

Here is my current code:

```
class DemoPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var activity: Activity

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
        when (call.method) {
            "demo" -> {
                result.success("Demo")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPluginBinding) {
        context = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext
        channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, channelName)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(binding: FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
    }

    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activity = binding.activity
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {}

    override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {}

    override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs of the FlutterPlugin Class you can do this in the MainActivity Class.

```kotlin
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        flutterEngine.plugins.add(DemoPlugin())  // add the plugin
    }
}
```